# Is there an npm cli option get package name from local package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json

I want to get details from `package.json` on the command line. An example:

```
$ cd ~/my-node-package
$ npm commandiamlookingfor package name
my-package-name
```

I know this would be a trivial script to write. I could do it like this:

```
node -e "try {var pack=require('./package.json'); console.log(pack.name); } catch(e) {}"
```

But any code I don't have to write (and maintain) is the best code. Also, since I want to use this for shell integrations it will run a lot; a native implementation would maybe be faster.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

NPM has environment variables that it stores. You can see these by typing `npm run env` in the console.

You can use this to get the variable you need by grepping for `npm_package_name` but that leaves you with "npm_package_name=your_package_name".

One way to get around it would be to get the substring after the "=" character with the command:

`cut -d "=" -f 2 <<< $(npm run env | grep "npm_package_name")`

This command leaves you with the package name.

EDIT:
Another way to do this is by adding a script in your `package.json` that is simply `echo $npm_package_name` then run that script in your shell command.

Your `package.json` would look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "your_package_name",
  "scripts": {
      "getName": "echo $npm_package_name"
  }
}
```

Then type `npm run getName -s`

Answer (score 17):

If you decide to go with your initial idea of using the `node` command, you could make it a bit cleaner by using the `-p` argument, which is shorthand for [`--print`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_p_print_script):

```
node -p "require('./package.json').name"
```

or with error handling

```
node -p "try { require('./package.json').name } catch(e) {}"
```

Comment: tip o' the hat for using `-p`

Answer (score 3):

I also needed this but I try to keep node out of it since I never know if the docker container I will be using to run the script will actually have node installed (this is also why I won't use jq). I usually use this shell script

```sh
npm run env | grep "npm_package_name" | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'
```

Basically what it does is

1. get env of npm package
2. grep the line with "npm_package_name"
3. split on "=" and return second entry

Answer (score 1):

If you are a sed-o-phile: `npm run env | sed -n '/npm_package_name/{s/.*=//;p;}'`

The `-n` switch suppress auto print

The `/npm_package_name/` address pattern selects for that line

`{` starts a command block

`s/.*=//;` substitutes everything through the equal sign with nothing

`p;` prints the buffer

`}` ends the command block

Answer (score 1):

For a while now, the npm cli has had this gem:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-pkg

so it means you can do this:

```bash
$ npm pkg get name
```

or

```bash
$ npm pkg set name "my-new-package-name"
```

for something more awesome:

```bash
pnpm --filter "packages/apps/*..." exec npm pkg get name
```

will print out the package names of all your monorepo packages that are used by  all your packages in the `packages/apps` directory.
Filtering is a feature of most monorepo sensitive package managers, [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/filtering#--filter-since) for example.

Comment: That's how it should be done today.